# jquery dynamic drop down

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display a drop down with numbers 0, 5, 10, ... 100 using jquery. I am writing the following code.

```
function addrow(index) {
    var a = '<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="css-checkbox" id="checkbox[]" /><label for="checkbox[]" class="css-label lite-x-red"></label>';
    var b = '<textarea name="question[]" id="bigarea" style="text-align:left;"></textarea>';
    var c = '<input type="checkbox" id="yes_checkbox[]" class="css-checkbox" name="qchecked[]" value="qchecked[]" /><label for="yes_checkbox[]" class="css-label lite-y-green"></label>';

    var d = $('<select id="effectdropdown[]" name="effect_dropdown[]" style="width:50px; height:25px;"></select>');
    for (var i = 0; i < 101; i = i + 5) {
        $('#effectdropdown').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    };
    var e = '<textarea id="smallarea" placeholder = "comments" name="comments[]"> </textarea>';
    var n = $('<tr><td align="center">' + a + '</td><td>' + b + '</td><td align="center">' + c + '</td><td align="center">' + d + '</td><td align="center">' + e + '</td></tr>');
    $('#checklist').append(n);
}
```

This code is returning the blank drop down. Could anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 2):

```
function dropdown() {
    var d = $('<select />').attr({
        id: "effectdropdown",
        name: "effect_dropdown[]"
        style: "width:50px; height:25px;"
    });

    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 101; i = i + 5) {
        options .= '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }

    d.append(options);
}
```

**ANOTHER WAY**

```
function dropdown() {
    $('body').append('<select id="effectdropdown" name="effect_dropdown[]" style="width:50px; height:25px;"></select>');

    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 101; i = i + 5) {
        options .= '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }

    $('#effectdropdown').append(options);
}
```

Comment: Tushar, I do not want to append it to the body, as i have more code i am working with where i need this drop down. so the first approach is acceptable, however, it is not working for me. it is not displaying the drop down at all.

Comment: @Maulik That's because you haven't added it in `DOM`

Comment: tushar, I edited the code for you. I have to add the drop down to the table row.

Comment: @Maulik Use 1st approach if the element is not in `DOM` use 2nd approach when the element to which you want to add `select` is available in `DOM`